# How to stream video from AWS S3 to an Angular 8 application using cloud Front

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, angular8, amazon-cloudfront

I have uploaded video on S3.

I stored the URL in mysql database.

Now I need to show those videos on angular8  UI  using Cloud Front

Let me know the possible ways

Comment: Similar query here : Solution : Amazon Elastic Encoder + Cloud Front   https://stackoverflow.com/q/41361407/6662460